# Multiple legends in pgfplot next to plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

[image]

I'm trying to replicate this graphic I found online because I really like it but its definition is terrible.
So far I managed to approximate the various plots it contains but I wasn't able to replicate the style of its legends... Anybody has an idea of how to do it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, 
                 xmax=1, 
                 ymin=0, 
                 ymax=1.2, 
                 grid=major, 
                 xlabel=$\lambda$, 
                 ylabel=$\mu$,
                 ylabel style={rotate={-90}},
                 width=12cm,
                 height=9cm]
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {1.296*(1-e^(-22.39*x)-0.398*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {1.37*(1-e^(-6.2*x)-0.488*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {1.197*(1-e^(-25.17*x)-0.45*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick]
            {0.855*(1-e^(-34.14*x)-0.403*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {0.41*(1-e^(-36.48*x)-0.318*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {0.204*(1-e^(-115.14*x)-0.364*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {0.06*(1-e^(-386.5*x)-0.17*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example add a `coordinate` with a `pin` at the end of each plot. I just did it for the first two, but do similar for the rest. You'll have to find an appropriate angle for the `pin` (`10` in the one example I did), as well as `pos`ition (`0.7` below). The second one shows how you can change the length of the `pin`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every pin/.append style={fill=white,draw},
   every pin edge/.append style={thick}
]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, 
                 xmax=1, 
                 ymin=0, 
                 ymax=1.2, 
                 grid=major, 
                 xlabel=$\lambda$, 
                 ylabel=$\mu$,
                 ylabel style={rotate={-90}},
                 width=12cm,
                 height=9cm]
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {1.296*(1-e^(-22.39*x)-0.398*x)}
            coordinate[pos=0.7,pin={10:road,dry}] (a);
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {1.37*(1-e^(-6.2*x)-0.488*x)}
            coordinate[pos=0.7,pin={[pin distance=1cm]10:cobblestones,dry}] (a);
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {1.197*(1-e^(-25.17*x)-0.45*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick]
            {0.855*(1-e^(-34.14*x)-0.403*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {0.41*(1-e^(-36.48*x)-0.318*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {0.204*(1-e^(-115.14*x)-0.364*x)};
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth, thick] 
            {0.06*(1-e^(-386.5*x)-0.17*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for